# joining two linq results which is not of same type using linq

Tags: sql, linq

i want to make a join query of two different linq result somebody please help
first result:

```
var result3 = (from i in db.SUP_Seek_Education
    group i.Univ_Name by new { i.Seek_Resume_ID } into g
    select new
    {
     count = g.Key.Seek_Resume_ID,
        Items = g.Select(w => w).Distinct()
    }).ToList().Select(o => new { o.count,uni= string.Join(",",o.Items.ToArray())});
```

and the second result is :

```
 var list = (from n in db.SUP_Seek_Personal
                join b in db.SUP_SeekerProfileImage on n.Seek_Per_ID equals b.Seek_Per_ID
                 into a
                from b in a.DefaultIfEmpty()
                join c in db.SUP_Seek_WebUser on n.Seek_Per_ID equals c.Seek_Per_ID
                join d in result2 on n.Seek_Per_ID equals d.Seek_Per_ID

                join e in result3 on d.Seek_Resume_ID equals e.count
                select new
                {
                    firtname = n.FirstName,
                    secondname = n.LastName,
                    // university = e.uni,
                    perid = n.Seek_Per_ID,
                    filename = b.ImageType,
                    imagetype = (b.ImageType == null ? "http://localhost:10057/JobSearch/images/advertisment/head-silhouette.png" : "http://localhost:10057/JobSearch/images/SeekerIMG/" + n.Seek_Per_ID + "." + b.ImageType)
                    // imagetype = (b == null ? Server.MapPath("~images/advertisment/head-silhouette.png") : b.ImageType)
                }
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want some kind of POCO ex:

```
    public class Element
    {
        internal string firtname { get; set; }
        internal string secondname { get; set; }
        internal decimal perid { get; set; }
        internal string filename { get; set; }
        internal string imagetype { get; set; }
        internal string uni { get; set; }
    }
```

when you create the list use **select new Element** and not **select new**. After that :

```
    foreach (var item in result3)
        list.FirstOrDefault(o => o.perid == item.count).uni = item.uni;
```

Helpful tip : Linq uses lazy loading but if you **.ToList()** query is materialized as data is pulled from database. In that case it would make sense to end line with **.ToList()**.

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding this is impossible. Sequences can be concatenated only if they have the same type; you could go for the common type `object` however.